# Possible to get Rails 4 working on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm working on a Rails 4 (using the release candidate) project and now need to collaborate with someone on a Windows machine. I can't even get a basic webpage to come up, however :(. It was quite a pain even installing sqlite3 using Ruby 2.0. Now, when I try to get a webpage up (I just created a dummy /home/index controller and view), I get this error:

```
Showing C:/Users/me/RubymineProjects/test_project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

  (in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-1.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):
3  <head>
4    <title>TestProject</title>
5    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
6    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
7    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8  </head>
9  <body>
```

Is Rails 4 just not ready for Windows yet? Using Ruby 2.0.0p195.

***UPDATE***: As per @szines request, here's the webpage output for

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/info/properties:
Ruby version    2.0.0 (x64-mingw32)
RubyGems version    2.0.3
Rack version    1.5
Rails version   4.0.0.rc1
JavaScript Runtime  JScript
Active Record version   4.0.0.rc1
Action Pack version 4.0.0.rc1
Action Mailer version   4.0.0.rc1
Active Support version  4.0.0.rc1
Middleware  
ActionDispatch::Static
Rack::Lock
#<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000000036b85c0>
Rack::Runtime
Rack::MethodOverride
ActionDispatch::RequestId
Rails::Rack::Logger
ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
ActionDispatch::Reloader
ActionDispatch::Callbacks
ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
ActiveRecord::QueryCache
ActionDispatch::Cookies
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
ActionDispatch::Flash
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
Rack::Head
Rack::ConditionalGet
Rack::ETag
Warden::Manager
Application root    C:/Users/me/RubymineProjects/test_project
Environment development
Database adapter    sqlite3
Database schema version 20130523073322
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this without turbolinks? Did you need the turbolinks gem?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that! I do want turbolinks.

Comment: did it include an error message?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - Isn't what I posted above an error message? Are you asking if there was a more specific error message? No, that's all I got.

Comment: What is your running environment? You can get it if you call this url in development mode: http://localhost:3000/rails/info/properties

Comment: @szines - I updated the question to include that output

Answer (score 21):

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Change this to :

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "defaults", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

It should work.

It will be great if someone can provide explanation for this.

More info:

[ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index (RoR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530042/execjsruntimeerror-in-usersindex-ror)

[ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: Hi, that didn't work for me, but if I change "application" for "defaults" in the line under it as well, it works afterward!

Comment: I tried airpaulg's suggestion and it worked for me. You need to change both.

Comment: install node.js--its the permanent solution (make sure to include npm/bin under your path in windows environment ).
by using "defaults" you are including defaults.js which doesn't exists. Check the browser console under network with 404-not found.

Answer (score 8):

**Just install node.js and the problem will gone.**

Explanation:
If you'll try to precompile assets, you'll get the following trace:

```
(in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-1.3.0/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
...
```

As you can see, there is a problem with ExecJS. ExecJS lets you run JavaScript code from Ruby and it requires one of the JS interpreters to be installed on your system. Here's [a list](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) of supported interpreters. Usually, you can use therubyracer which is just V8 but there are problems with compiling V8 under the windows. So you can choose another option - NodeJS. ExecJS will use it automatically when you'll install NodeJS and add it to your PATH.

Answer (score 6):

changing following line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "defaults", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

works.

**OR**

you can install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.25/node-v0.10.25-x86.msi)

Comment: I had the same problem running Rails on Windows using Railsinstaller (the latest version as of today). Replacing "application" with "defaults" worked. Installing node.js did not.

Comment: make sure you add "npm/bin" in your path (windows enviornment)

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution for getting Turbolinks to work on Windows 8 x64 is posted at [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial), option 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem for a while and it's that on windows jquery and coffee script are not functional in their latest update and finally i found this wonderful method that worked perfectly without the need to download node or escape //require tree. So all you need is configure the settings in your runtimes.rb which lives in execjs to be like this- you will find this part with few differences fix them and you'll be good to go.

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
:name        => "JScript",
:command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
:runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
:encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
```

You can watch this video for detailed solution.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5i94L17KPo