# JSON::ParserError in ROR / turbolinks error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I have just started following sample app "depot" from the Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book and have go to Part 2 , Chapter 6 Creating the application section (given for as a reference for those with the book). Obviously this is meant to be absolutely beginner basics and Im copying what is typed in but I have hit an error immediately that I would like some help with.
I have created the app with rails new depot , i made a small change to the db migration file as instructed and everything works ok . I started the server but when I went to localhost:3000/products (which the correct url) it gives the following error in the browser:

```
Showing D:/Dropbox/ROR/depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

757: unexpected token at '[0x7FFFCA469260] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
[0x7FFFCA4643B0] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
'
  (in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
Rails.root: D:/Dropbox/ROR/depot
```

Looking at the error I opened application.html.erb and removed line 6 that read:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Removing this stopped the error and the app runs as expected which is fine , but I would like to understand why this error is happening and how to fix it as i don't want to just remove this line if it may effect something else further down the line (i.e. better to understand and fix now)

I have also tried running gem install turbolinks incase i needed to install that. I stopped server and ran bundle install after doing that but still get same error.

Am i right in thinking that it is turbolinks that is the cause of the error (as removing that line fixes the problem).
Any idea how to fix this.

I am on windows 8.1 64 bit , Ruby ruby 2.1.5p273 , RAILS 4.2.0 -  i am a ROR newbie also so sorry if I havent supplied any obvious info for troubleshooting this - let me know if I should post further info.

Comment: I also found this thread [link ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739581/possible-to-get-rails-4-working-on-windows)   that suggests changing applcation to defaults in that line - i have tried that and it works but I dont understand WHY it works

Comment: Already discovered that it caused a problem  - the Destroy links / delete method wont work without it is seems. If i remove it or change it to 'defaults'. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Basically decided that ROR on windows in more hassle than it is worth by the looks of things. Installed ubuntu in a virtualbox machine and put ROR on that.