# ExecJS::RuntimeError when converting .js to .js.coffee

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, coffeescript

I've been charged with changing a PHP application to a RoR application. Everything's going well, but turbolinks is causing me some trouble. In order to fix this, I've decided to convert the existing `.js` libraries to `.js.coffee`

I have two `.js` libraries:

```
lightbox-2.6.js
modernizr.custom.js
```

These work perfectly. 
After converting these `.js` files to `.js.coffee` I incur the following error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Application#gallery
```

Installing node.js does not fix the problem.

Removing

```
//= require_tree .
```

from `app/javascripts/application.js` does solve the problem. However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530042/execjsruntimeerror-in-usersindex-ror), removing this require method means that there is

> an actual problem with ExecJS working properly with the JavaScript
>   runtime on your system

Okay, I'll admit I don't really understand what to do with this. The .js works perfectly. When converted to .js.coffee this problem arises. I don't actually know what ExecJS is, either. Could someone clarify what's going on here? Why it doesn't work at all when converted to js.coffee and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your `Gemfile`

> gem 'therubyracer'

and then `bundle install`

Comment: hold on I was afk! :P

Comment: afk means? well if this helped you, mark this as an answer so that others also can benefit with it