# Emberjs running on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

creating new application using ruby on rails for EmberJs and when running "rails s" on ubuntu 14.04 getting following error

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

To resolve above error, tried following cases.
1) As already posted question reading above error
[ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index (RoR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530042/execjsruntimeerror-in-usersindex-ror)
  a) changed **~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb**
  b) changed **~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4.1/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb**

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
    :name        => "JScript",
    :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
    :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
    :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

but still getting same error.

2) If commented out **//= require vendor** in **/app/assets/javascripts/application.js**. Then above error will disappear. Then getting following errors
**TypeError: Ember.ApplicationController is undefined**
**TypeError: Ember.ApplicationView is undefined**

3) if changing

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Then getting error **NetworkError: 404 Not Found localhost:3000/javascripts/default.js**

Setup Details:
1) ruby --version **ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]**
2) rails --version **Rails 4.1.7**
3) gem --version **2.4.4**
4) nodejs --version **v0.10.33**

Nothing seems to be work, Can anyone through light to resolve issue?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: The things you are doing tell me that you are completely lost on what is going on, I highly recommend that you follow a rails tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine with following changes.
1) placed the files[**ember.js,handlerbars.js and jquery.js**] in **/vendor/assets/javascripts**.
   Note these files were downloaded from http://emberjs.com/ under StartKit.
2) included line **//= require_tree ../../../vendor/.** under **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing ember js into your vender/assets you're doing it wrong. Most JavaScript libraries are compiled into gems for easier use in Rails and ember is no exception. Try this tutorial instead and use ember-rails or your project will likely have issues down the line.

http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/setting-up-an-ember-app-with-a-rails-backend

Oh also, make sure to remove the calls to turbolinks cuz that does not place nice with ember