# TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, therubyracer, execjs

I have created rails application where I created a database (empty).  When I try to view my products page, I receive the following error on my http://localhost:3000/products page.  Before migrating the database, the application did function.  I am using therubyracer and am on Windows 7.

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Products#index
Showing C:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/home/JP/nameofapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #16 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #16):

13     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
14     
15     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
16     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
17     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
18     
19   </head>

Rails.root: C:/RailsInstaller/DevKit/home/JP/nameofapp
```

This is what I got on the Rails server:

```
Started GET "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-23 22:28:06 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"
Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
  Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3391ms

ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or
method
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/
assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)):
    13:   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.mi
n.js"></script>
    14:
    15:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolin
ks-track' => true %>
    16:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => t
rue %>
    17:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    18:
    19: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts_application_h
tml_erb__912949727_56715336'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
 (6.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within
 rescues/layout (27.0ms)
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: One potential cause of this could be that the gem you installed is outdated or needs to be updated to a more current version. Have you tried removing 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, just to see if that changes anything?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I do have the latest: execjs 2.5.2 and turbolinks 2.5.3.  When I removed the   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>, it worked as FYI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails-4, ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241981/rails-4-execjsprogramerror-in-pageswelcome)

Comment: Below mentioned link, help me to fix the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial

Answer (score 9):

The error occurs because there is some problem finding the correct assets which are located in app/assets. To resolve the issue, you can following below steps.

Add **gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'** into Gemfile and run **bundle install** then
Run **bundle update coffee-script-source**
Restart rails server
Or there is a dirty workaround which is to change the code from

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "default", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "default", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

But note this workaround doesn't really resolve the application issue, it just makes your application works without expected stylesheets and javascripts.

Comment: I just added 'gem coffee-rails' and then bundled and everything is back to normal. Just in case this helps anyone, I'm working on windows and built the project using the 'without coffeescript' command.

Comment: gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' was the solution. Even coffee-script-source 1.12 still doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: 3 years later and this is still a problem.  And this is still the solution.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I removed the require_tree from application.js and it worked

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require turbolinks 
// require_tree .
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem and brings up issues with any gem/dependency relying on the js portion of the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

I think Best Solution is Removing the slashes in application.js file like

```
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
= require turbolinks
= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue too, checkout the extensive solution on this thread,  [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial/14118913#14118913) by @Kevin P.  Also,the solution by, @evedoevelli, on another thread: [Rails ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome/28436913#28436913) works. I used the second solution with it been the most recent date-wise.

Comment: Last one link had help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Upon careful research this is the solution I stumbled upon. Just make sure you have the latest version of [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org) installed. After installing NodeJs, make sure you restart our system. However it is very important that you update your windows OS. You should be fine. If you are using [RubyMine](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnz9GZwY_SAhWrL8AKHegJBy0QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetbrains.com%2Fruby%2F&usg=AFQjCNF05YuOBFG5dFLqK7A14hCiD9qPhw&sig2=SAQZxDqP8291nMI6pjHALA) everything should work by now. No need to be troubling your head over the coffee-script issue. The ExecJs Program error seem to be more related to the NodeJs and its associated modules.

Answer (score 2):

For me,solution was to remove-

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

from

> app\views\layout\application.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) is not installed. If you install it, the problem should go away.

However, this would work as well in `application.js`:

```js
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require turbolinks 
// require_tree .
```

But this is just not the prefered method because all this does is disable rails functionality. For example, ActionCable will not work with this change.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use layouts, put "layout false" in the controller file, just below class title:

class ABCController < ApplicationController
"layout false"
  def index
...
..