# bundle exec rake assets:precompile fails in Dev Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my `development.rb` file

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

and when I run the command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`, I get the following error.

```
Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-
```

Comment: you working on windows.?

Comment: @athar: yes. Windows 8

Comment: i added the answer along with reference. hope that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

and do this

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

Reference: [Rails-4, ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241981/rails-4-execjsprogramerror-in-pageswelcome)

Answer (score 1):

if you use Windows, try to install NodeJS and restart the computer.
Should be run.

Comment: Thanks Pierangelo. Cheers :)