# Error on loading CSS using Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing my first small test Project using ruby on rails and I'm getting na error when trying to load css into my page.
My view has a small form to save events on Google Calendar, the code is shown below.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<div id="content">

  <h1>SAVE AN EVENT</h1>

  <form action="/google_calendar/create" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_dates()" >
    <fieldset>
      <label for="title">Title:</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="textbox" />
      <label for="begindate">Begin Date:</label><input type="date" name="begindate" id="begindate" class="time" />
      <label for="beginhour">Begin Hour:</label><input type="time" name="beginhour"  id="beginhour" class="time" />
      <label for="enddate">End Date:</label><input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate" class="time" />
      <label for="endhour">End Hour:</label><input type="time" name="endhour" id="endhour" class="time" />
      <label for="location">Location:</label><input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="textbox" size="31" class="textbox" />
      <label for="description">Description:</label><textarea rows="10" cols="25" name="description" id="description" class="textbox"></textarea>
      <input type="Submit" value="Save"  class="button"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <span id="result_message">
  <%= @result_message %>
  </span>
</div>
```

In my application.css I have the following styles.
I know I could put them in a diferente file, but since this is just a small test I left there.
The file has the following code.

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

body, div, h1, form, fieldset, input, textarea {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #728eaa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #25303C 0%, #728EAA 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#25303C), color-stop(100%,#728EAA)); /* webkit */
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#content {
    width: 430px; margin: 60px auto; padding: 60px 30px;
    background: #c9d0de; border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px; color: #445668; text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center; margin: 0 0 35px 0; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
}

label {
    float: left; clear: left; margin: 11px 20px 0 0; width: 95px;
    text-align: right; font-size: 16px; color: #445668;
    text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
}

span {
    float: left; clear: left; margin: 11px 20px 0 0;
    text-align: right; font-size: 16px; color: #445668;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
}

input {
    width: 260px; height: 35px; padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    background: #5E768D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #546A7F 0%, #5E768D 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#546A7F), color-stop(20%,#5E768D)); /* webkit */
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
    color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;
}

textarea {
    width: 260px; height: 170px; padding: 12px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    background: #5E768D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #546A7F 0%, #5E768D 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#546A7F), color-stop(20%,#5E768D)); /* webkit */
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71;
}
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
    color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;
}
textarea:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background: #728eaa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #668099 0%, #728eaa 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#668099), color-stop(20%,#728eaa)); /* webkit */
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 185px; height: 52px; float: right; padding: 10px 15px; margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border: 1px solid #556f8c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #718DA9 0%, #415D79 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#718DA9), color-stop(100%,#415D79)); /* webkit */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The thing is that when I'm trying to access the form I'm getting this error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/RubyOnRailsCalendar/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb where line #1 raised: 
TypeError: The object doesn't support this property or method (translated from my native language)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: I added the following line to my application.html.erb but it's still failing.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

The complete file is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>RubyOnRailsCalendar</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Gemfile added

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'google_calendar', '~> 0.5.1'

gem 'openssl'
```

Comment: in `application.html.erb` you have to load all your styles next string `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: I added that to the file but it's still failing.

Comment: do you have `default.css` file in `assets/stylesheets` ?

Comment: No. I only have the application.css file and imported it in the view.

Comment: just remove `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: It still didn't work. I also tried removing the include from the view and only using it on application.html.erb and it's giving me the same error on this file.
Do you know if I need a specific gem for this?

Comment: show, please, your gemfile

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: Another thing I've tried was creating a default.css file and add the styles there, but the same error occurs.

Comment: I think you're trying to develop in Windows

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to mention that. I used RailsInstaller.

Comment: I've heard about issues of developing in windows, but all what I can help you is googling, because I use ubuntu.

Comment: [first post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit) ||  [second post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome)  ||  [third post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241981/rails-4-execjsprogramerror-in-pageswelcome)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for trying to help.