# Error while i am try to run simple rails app.how can i solve it? i got type error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ptrms</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks 
track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' 
%>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails-4, ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241981/rails-4-execjsprogramerror-in-pageswelcome)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the default Windows JavaScript runtime and the current CoffeeScript library are incompatible.

The simplest ways to fix it are to

1. install NodeJS (and make sure it's on your `PATH` so Rails can find it), or
2. avoid CoffeeScript (e.g. use the `--skip-coffee` option to `rails new`)