# No route matches [GET] "/links/1/like" with acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to implement acts_as_votable gem as shown in this this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-1HCWbu7iU

Seems everything is workigng fine, except when I click on upvote or downvote, I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/links/1/like"
```

This is the code for upvote / downvote function

```
<span class="upvote">
          <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "upvote-image" do %>
          <% end %>
</span>
```

This is the routes.rb file:

```
  resources :links do
    member do
      put "like", to:    "links#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end

    resources :comments
  end
```

Here are the upvote and downvote actions in links_controller

```
def upvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this, and I'm posting it here in case there are others with the same problem.

I'm developing on Windows. I had problems with javascript, and followed this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972253/1690091

This removed the javascript related errors that were popping all over the place, but this is NOT the solution. This simply removed js from my app.

**The real solution is here:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331807/1690091

You need to use a proper version of coffee script, that's compatible with Windows.

To sum things up:

js file was missing from my app, and therefore `//= require jquery_ujs` was also missing, and that's why all of my links were being called as GET.

@Rich Peck,
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is down to your link having a `GET` method, rather than `PUT`:

`No route matches [GET] "/links/1/like"`

I can only surmise that your `link_to` code is not written correctly:

```
<span class="upvote">
   <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "upvote-image" %>
</span>
```

Your other code looks good. If you test this, the best thing to do will be to show the pure HTML for the link in your question - this will give us the ability to see whether it's being rendered correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<span class="upvote">
  <%= link_to like_path, method: :put, class: "upvote-image" do %>
  <% end %>
</span>
```

Comment: This is an incorrect usage of the `link_to` method. We shouldn't condone this.