# Type Error with Active Admin - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am new to Ruby on Rails(4.1.8) and using OS Windows 8, I have added the gem activeadmin in my gemfile and ran commands

```
rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

but I get the following exception while running http://localhost:3000/admin

> TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method   (in
>   c:/Sites/CleverChalk/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee)

Could someone please advise why this occurs. i read a couple of post on 
 `coffee-script-source` and
 `coffee-rails` but they have not worked for me.

My Gemfile is as below :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Comment: See if answers from this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit

Comment: what version of `coffee-script` are you using? can you show your `Gemfile`?

Comment: I updated it to --> gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

Comment: Edited the question.. it now contains the gemfile

Comment: Does it work after you updated to `'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'`?

Comment: show us your code for active_admin.js.coffee.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much for your help. I could resolve the issue by reinstalling active admin but this time with Users.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by reinstalling activeadmin with Users that meant adding the devise gem as shown below:

```
gem 'devise'
```

to the gemfile and then

```
bundle install
rails generate devise:install
```

Thanks.