# Getting error on CSS with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run this i get the error:
Sass::SyntaxError in Welcome#index error
index.html.erb:

These are my ruby files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome.scss" %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <p id = "title">Welcome To Dot</p>
        </div>
        <h1>Make Life Easier</h1>
        <h2>Enter</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Welcome.scss:

```
#title{
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: #0b1e40;
    text-align: left;
}

#header{
    background-color: sandybrown;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;    
}
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Gemstones:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

I'm not sure why im getting this.  If I changed 'application' back to 'default' I no longer get the error but the CSS does not show up on the webpage.  This is my first Ruby On Rails project so I would appreciate any help.

> ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index
>   Showing C:/Users/Michael/Projects/dot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   Rails.root: C:/Users/Michael/Dropbox/Docs/Homework/Projects/dot
>
> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__35629208_74953452'

Comment: Have you installed the proper gems to use SCSS/SASS with Rails? You need to install `gem 'sass'` and `gem 'sass-rails'` for SASS to work.

Comment: And you're missing a semicolon at the end of the titles `color` value, too.

Comment: yeah i found the semicolon but I didn't have those gems installed.  I'm doing that now so hopefully that was the problem!

Comment: SASS is a compiler for SCSS files, they will be compiled and the output is a normal CSS file which is then used, because browsers do not understand SCSS. But for a developer it is easier to work with the SASS syntax, because of `@extend` and `mixins` and so on...

Comment: @AlexanderTrust I installed those gems but I am still getting this error: ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index

Comment: This probably results because you deleted the turbolink js. If you use the turbolinks gem this line is necessary. If you deactivate the turbolinks gem it should suspend the error. I guess, because I don't know what the whole error is.

Comment: I'm not sure what the turbolinks gem is or if I am using this but the line in my application.html.erb file is still:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: @AlexanderTrust I added the full error in my question.

Comment: Turbolinks is installed by default with a new rails (4.x) project. It is a bunch of Ajax-methods for faster loading of websites, by preloading of links and so on. In your gemfile the should be a `gem 'turbolinks'`.

Comment: @AlexanderTrust I added my gemfile to the question.  It has turbolinks.

Comment: It's just beneath `gem 'jquery-rails'` **but** don't mess with it right now. Just go back to the default with those 3 lines. This makes sure that the application's asset pipeline is properly loaded. As for this pipeline, there are rules. Do you have a `Welcome` controller and views for it? If not the welcome.scss is not loaded by default, you either have to @import it in the `application.scss`, but better would be, just paste the content from your welcome.scss to the application.scss - this is loaded on every view.

Comment: @AlexanderTrust I added my welcome controller and my view for it is index.html.erb.  So since I have the welcome controller do I need to import it into the application.scss or not? Thanks

Comment: No, then it should be loaded automatically whenever the index, or other views of your welcome controller are loaded, but then only. This is a good way to separate styles for individual controllers/models, if you follow the naming convention that is. But it's confusing at first. And make sure that you can access the index by adding a proper route. Just asking, maybe you already have a whole `resources :welcome` in your routes file.

Comment: Ups, did not recognize you pasted your `routes.rb` too, so yes you're good then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missing semicolon** (if you've ever done PHP, it would be one of the first things you'd look for):

```
#title{
  color: #0b1e40;
}
```

---

Looking around, the error you have seems to be this:

> Object doesn't support this property or method Rails.root

This suggests a problem with your *routes*:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "welcome#index" #-> you don't need (get "welcome#index")
```

--

You may also have an issue with `ExecJS` (the class which runs javascript on your system) -- if you're using Windows, you should [**download `nodeJS`**](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), install and run it, restarting your rails server in the meantime.

This should solve the problem with calling `application` vs `default` in your layout.

Comment: Yes! node.js was the problem.  I wish Ruby would let you know this in their tutorial.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error in your `welcome.scss`
you forgot the `;`

```
#title{
  ...
  color: #0b1e40;
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you... (if you use rails on windows)

How to fix error

Navigate to \app\views\layouts\application.html.erb

Change line 6 from

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'defaults', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

And you’re done!

i found it on next url

http://mech.xyz/how-to-fix-ruby-on-rails-turbolinks-js-coffee-error-windows/

Answer (score -1):

Use the assets pipeline. Just place your Welcome.scss into app/assets/stylesheets. Remove `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome.scss" %>`

Comment: Thanks I deleted that line but I am still getting this error: ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index Showing C:/Users/Michael/Projects/dot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: What is written in line 5 of your application.html.erb?

Comment: @Mike do you have `gem 'turbolinks'` in your gemfile?

Comment: @AlexanderTrust This is line 5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: @nobilik I do have turbolinks,  I added my gemfile to the question so you can check it.

Comment: Windows? Maybe same story http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit ?