# Action Controller: Exception Caught

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and started learning in a french website called openclassroom. So in the instructions it tells me to create an html page using this command:

```
$ rails g controller pages home #we are launching our webpage
$ rails server #we launch our server
```

When I try accessing [http://locahost:3000/pages/home](http://localhost:3000/pages/home) it gives me an error. The screen looks like this...

[Link to the image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwvP8.png)

Here's the page in the directory for `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Castor</title>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   </head>
   <body>

     <%= yield %>

   </body>
 </html>
```

This is my routes file which can be found in `config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'pages/home'
end
```

This is my home page located in `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`

```
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
```

Although I don't think the problems come from here.
Here is my GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes 
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.16.14.7'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: @kings man here you go

Comment: Also post your `views/pages/home.html.erb`.

Comment: @Vucko I posted this but I don't think the problem comes from here..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object doesn't support this property or method Rails Windows 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit)

Comment: @Vucko Where do you find JScript in `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\execjs-2.6.0\lib\execjs\runtime.rb`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error after clicking `Full Trace`?

Comment: @PJSCopeland Hi, what do you mean by clicking _Full Trace_?

Comment: Now that I look at it again, I might be barking up the wrong tree - but on the error page in your browser, there's a **Full Trace** link above the stack trace - on the same line as **Application Trace** and **Framework Trace**.

Comment: What I'm vaguely wondering - and trying to confirm - is whether the line `Rails.application.routes.draw` in `config/routes.rb` is doing anything weird - following the convention of other apps I've seen, I'm wondering if `Castor::Application.routes.draw` would work instead.