# TypeError when acessing manifest file using stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Ruby on Rails app, following the tutorials on lynda.com, and I'm having a problem with the asset pipeline. I wrote a very short css file called admin, and added it to the manifest file (which is in the app/assets/stylesheets) directory like so:

`*= require_self
 *= require admin
 *= require_tree .`

Now, when I add the stylesheet helper to the main page with a reference to my manifest file, like this: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag("application") %>`, I get a TypeError when I load my application. If I change it to `<%= stylesheet_link_tag("default") %>`, my page loads without an error, but I don't know what it's referring to and there's no styling.

I'm sure I'm missing some intermediate step - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit What is the error exactly?

Comment: Could it be that your SASS isn't compiling successfully? Also, what is the name of your admin CSS file? What files do you have under `app/assets/stylesheets`? You likely don't even need `*= require admin` as you're using `*= require_tree .` which recursively includes everything in the current directory from which it is called.

Comment: if you're running your rails app on windows downgrade your  coffee script to `gem coffee-script-source', '1.8.0` as @FrederickCheung mentioned to the link

Comment: @Jonathon I doubt that my SASS isn't compiling correctly, but I was just following a tutorials when setting up projects, so it is possible/ My admin file is called admin.css, and is found in the same directory as the application file.