# Ruby on Rails : TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm encountering the following error when i try to run a dynamic web page for practice:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Extracted source (around line #7):
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
```

I get this on my prompt as well:

```
Started GET "/example/test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-01 13:00:03 -0500
Processing by ExampleController#test as HTML
  Rendering example/test.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered example/test.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1984ms

ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method):
    4:     <title>Demoproject</title>
    5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    6:
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    9:   </head>
   10:
```

test.html.erb

```
<h1>Dynamic Web Page Using ERB</h1>
<% sum = 0 %>
<% for i in 1..5 %>
<%= "#{i}" %>
<% sum = sum + i %>
<% end %>
<p>The sum is:
<%= "#{sum}" %>
</p>
```

application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

example_controller.rb

```
 class ExampleController < ApplicationController

      def test

      end

    end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    end
```

Versions:
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 5.1.1

I'm using Win10. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you add the `test` view?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Add your ExampleController

Comment: Which Rails and Ruby version are you using, have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972253/5025116)?

Comment: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

Rails 5.1.1

Comment: The asset "defaults.css" is not present in the asset pipeline. This is what i'm getting when i change to defaults. Not even when i change it to default.