# Rails coffeescript : TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have the following rails configuration:

```
Windows 7
Rails 4.1.1
Ruby 2.0.0p481
Gem: coffee-rails 4.0.1
Gem: coffee-script 2.3.0
Gem: coffee-script-source 1.9.1
```

I have an application that was working fine, but now doesn't. I don't recall changing anything (`git diff` doesn't reveal anything). The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in c:/Users/mbratc01/Documents/Rails/manpower/app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #9):
 7 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
 8 <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.11.1', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
 9 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
10 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
11 </head>
```

I really have no Coffeescript items going on yet. The contents of `welcome.js.coffee` are:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
```

I found that if I just move this file to another, inaccessible location, the application runs fine. Also, putting just an empty `.coffee` file in the `app/assets/javascript` folder generates the same error above.

I've seen a couple of posts here on StackOverflow that looked very similar, but after reading through them, I couldn't find the root cause of my problem nor could I resolve it without just getting rid of the `.coffee` file. I suspect there's something not quite right with the CoffeeScript capability setup here, but not sure what that is given that the right gems appear to be installed.

Anyone have a suggestion on what could be causing this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I need to do to get the blog to work in rails 4.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240245/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-the-blog-to-work-in-rails-4-2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According tho [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit), CoffeeScript doesn't play well with Windows. You may want to try downgrading the version of CoffeeScript or completely removing it from your Gemfile.

Then just rename the `.coffee` file to a plain `.js` and rock regular javascript in your Rails app.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that and I guess I was looking for confirmation. It had been working fine without a thought until now. But I don't mind removing it. I haven't really been using it for this project. Forcing `coffee-script-source` to `1.8.0` as suggested in that link worked as well.

Comment: This is still a problem, as a client's legacy (3.2.18) Rails app all of a sudden started doing the same thing.  Re-writing all the *.js.coffee files to regular *.js fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think renaming extension is not good solution. Try following:

Add to Gemfile

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

then, run

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

and restart the server (if needed)