# Ruby on Rails: Why doesn't my delete link work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, crud

I am following the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

and I have the following line in my index.html.erb:

```
 <%= link_to 'Destroy', team_path(team), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

But it doesn't work; it just goes to the show page.

For your information, this is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'bets/index'
  root 'bets#index'
  resources :teams
end
```

My controller:

```
def destroy
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @team.destroy
    redirect_to teams_path
end
```

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs .
```

My application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'defaults', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Please note that I have tried changing `<%= javascript_include_tag 'defaults', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` to `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`, but this gives me the following error:

```
 Showing C:/Sites/BettingSite/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
(in C:/Sites/BettingSite/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
```

Line 6 is the line: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You have `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` required twice in your `application.js` file. Try removing the second ones.

Comment: try this `<%= link_to 'Destroy', team, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Comment: Thanks for your advice (both Ryan K and Athar), I've just tried those suggestions, they didn't work

Comment: Also make sure you spell "application" correctly. It seems like your `javascript_include_tag` misspells "application" (it reads "applicationn"). Also, what is on line 18 of `application.js`?

Comment: And a third thing: make sure that there is a period after require_tree. Like this: `//= require_tree .`

Comment: @RyanK, thank you for pointing that out, I have edited my question accordingly and updated the error message. I don't know what the code is on line 18 in `application.js` but I have seen it advised to use here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154916/rails-4-link-to-destroy-not-working-in-getting-started-tutorial

Comment: @RyanK I also just tried the `//= require_tree .` but no joy

Comment: can you try one more thing please.. remove these `//= require jquery` and 
`//= require jquery_ujs .` from the end and simply add `.` after tree.  also please share the rake routes output.

Comment: As per the error message check this link.. it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882182/rails-coffeescript-typeerror-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the problem is that Windows is not working well with CoffeeScript. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit), add this gem to your `gemfile`:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.9.1'
```

That, or remove all CoffeeScript from your code by renaming your `.coffee` or `.js.coffee` files to regular `.js` files (and, of course, changing your CoffeeScript code to regular JavaScript). You would also have to remove any CoffeeScript gems from your `gemfile`.

BTW, when you update your `gemfile`, you must run `bundle install` and then restart your server.

Comment: I've just tried the first part and it hasn't worked, I can't see where I have any `.coffee` or `.js.coffee` files

Comment: It would be under `app/assets/javascripts`.

Comment: Yeah I can't see any in there

Comment: So if you're not going to use Coffeescript (which I would still try to use, but if it doesn't work...), then remove the CoffeeScript gem (I believe its `coffee-rails`) and the `coffee-script-source` gem, run `bundle install`, and restart your server.

Comment: Ok, so I just re-read the error message. It's having problems with the `turbolinks` gem (which uses coffeescript). Replace the line `//= require turbolinks` with `// require turbolinks`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84277/discussion-between-ryan-k-and-benjs-1).