# Rails :TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just freshly installed rails and generated my new rails app files and pages and started my server. but when i start my server and run localhost:3000 in browser i am getting the error

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method`
```

it saysShowing `C:/Users/walnut/Desktop/projects/walden/walden/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:`

```
application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Walden</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using windows machine?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882182/rails-coffeescript-typeerror-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method

Comment: @Pavan yes...its windows i am using

Comment: Then look into the links suggested by @Dipak.

Comment: @Dipak   Superb...got it working now.

Comment: @Pavan....thank you.