# css not loading on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi guys new to rails and I'm playing around with it but I cannot get the CSS to load. I'm on windows

This is my application.css file

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self


body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>      true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could You check inspector panel in chrome and click on network tab to find requests that makes error? I think Your css file is not accessible public-ly to be retrieved by browser

Comment: Do you get any erros in browser console or in your rails server?

Comment: You have a random closing </div> with no opening div under yield

Comment: @brad I was getting an error on application.html.erb file
 so I had to change 'application' to 'default' and that fixed the error but unfortunately the css is not loading

Comment: @num8er I think you may be right I'm getting a 404 status on the css, I think it's because I have it linking to 'default' instead of 'application' but I had to do this to get rails working on windows

Comment: @Carl I know it's stupid, but just copy that css to public folder and try to access it.

Comment: @Carl revert it from `default` to `application` and use this code: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>` (without `'data-turbolinks-track' => true`)  so, if it will work, it means that You've error in Your css file that turbolinks cannot process or configuration of assets pipeline is wrong.

Comment: @num8er Getting this error when I revert 'default' to 'application' 

"Showing C:/Users/carl/Desktop/leanRails/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:"

Comment: so it means that it's trying to use turbolinks to watch Your css file, but because of first lines in Your css it's crashing to read first lines. please read my answer and try to check. and if it does not work, please put somewhere whole body of error.

Answer (score 0):

Your application.html.erb miss tag body. There is only close `</body>` without open

You are wrong at `stylesheet_link_tag    'default'` and `javascript_include_tag 'default'`. Change `default` to `application`

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Btw, on your `body`, you have a close `div` without open

Comment: Hey, I added the opening body tag but still not working

Comment: Ah, you are wrong at `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default'`. I update my answer

Comment: I had to change to default becasue of an error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome

Comment: About the error above. I see many ways to resolved it without change `application` to `default`. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882182/rails-coffeescript-typeerror-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method). But I suggest you should develop rails on linux or mac or [c9io](https://c9.io/)

Comment: Yeah rails seems to have a lot of error on windows, I think I might use linux

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with css that cannot be processed by turbolinks and makes rails crash.

Replace:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

to:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

and revert:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: Unfortunely when I try this I get an ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index
error

Comment: @Carl `ExecJS::ProgramError` ? can You screenshot or put somewhere full body of error?