# Getting ActionView::Template::Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to Rails and following tutorial video, but when I followed then now am getting error:

[image]

The step that I followed was I generate a controller by following this command.

```
rails g controller greeter hello
```

Then started rails server and typed //localhost:3000/greeter/hello

There I got this error message:

[image]

I haven't change any default, which was created by Rails.

How can get this page display. I even checked `route.rb` but it was fine.

Comment: here is my file which i have created https://github.com/jhamlal/Coursera_rail.git

Comment: Try replacing `application` with `default`, line 7  and 8 in `application.html.erb`.

Comment: Are you on windows / Internet Explorer? If yes, this could be because of the coffeescript in turbolinks. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240245/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-the-blog-to-work-in-rails-4-2)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5n8izNm8EYOSVlKVUNOZmlTWnM

Comment: I have followed both and update file on git also.