# I intalled node.js why am i still getting the error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

[ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index (RoR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530042/execjsruntimeerror-in-usersindex-ror/28598402#28598402)

Im trying to install Rails. In fact im pretty sure everything is installed. I tried it without node.js , but the tutorial i was using to install recomended i just download node js. I still got the error mentioned in the link above. wich was recomended in the comments section of the tutorial.

here is some stuff.

```
C:\row>cd dev

C:\row\dev>cd dev

C:\row\dev\dev>cd hello_world   

C:\row\dev\dev\hello_world>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8EF3-315B

 Directory of C:\row\dev\dev\hello_world

02/14/2015  07:44 PM    <DIR>          .
02/14/2015  07:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/14/2015  07:41 PM               474 .gitignore
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          app
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          bin
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          config
02/14/2015  07:41 PM               153 config.ru
02/14/2015  07:57 PM    <DIR>          db
02/14/2015  07:41 PM             1,475 Gemfile
02/14/2015  07:44 PM             4,110 Gemfile.lock
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          lib
02/14/2015  07:54 PM    <DIR>          log
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          public
02/14/2015  07:41 PM               249 Rakefile
02/14/2015  07:41 PM               478 README.rdoc
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          test
02/14/2015  08:03 PM    <DIR>          tmp
02/14/2015  07:41 PM    <DIR>          vendor
               6 File(s)          6,939 bytes
              12 Dir(s)  100,006,662,144 bytes free


C:\row\dev\dev\hello_world>rails s
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-02-14 21:16:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-02-14 21:16:35] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-02-14 21:16:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2336 port=3000


Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for ::1 at 2015-02-14 21:17:27 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"
Processing by Rails::InfoController#properties as */*
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/temp
lates/rails/info/properties.html.erb (30.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 467ms (Views: 361.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/users" for ::1 at 2015-02-14 21:17:54 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users"):
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_
call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (57.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (381.0ms
)


Started GET "/users" for ::1 at 2015-02-14 21:19:01 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users"):
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_
call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_
dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (351.0ms
)
[2015-02-14 21:25:20] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2015-02-14 21:25:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? ^C

C:\row\dev\dev\hello_world>rails c
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0>
irb(main):002:0*
irb(main):003:0* Rails.root: C:/row/dev/dev/hello_world
SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected ':'
Rails.root: C:/row/dev/dev/hello_world
           ^
(irb):3: unknown regexp options - dv
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error `No route matches [GET] "/users"` doesn't have anything to do with your javascript runtime.  Rather, you are missing the route for your user index. In your tutorial, find the spot where you add the user routes to your `config/routes.rb` file. It probably looks like  `resources :users`...